# How do I test GOF of a small sample against an arbitrary distribution in R

Tags: r, design-patterns

I’d like to do a GOF test on a small set of data (around 50 samples) against a defined distribution. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Example distribution:

```
n <- 50
time.vec <- 1:n 
alpha <- 0.6
test.dist.vec <- 1/(time.vec^alpha)
```

Example data to be fit against test.dist.vec:

```
my.jitter <- runif(n, min=-0.05, max=0.1) 
test.data <- test.dist.vec + my.jitter
```

Given the above, how can test the significance of test.data against test.dist.vec?

Additionally, given a sample test.data with a small n (around 50 – but what is min anyway?), how do I estimate alpha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test work for you. 
If yes:

```
ks.test(test.data,test.dist.vec)
```

In fact, there's a bunch of those kind of test.

Comment: Interesting. Yes. That works. Thank you.Any tips on estimating getting alpha?

Comment: An estimation procedure like OLS or maximum likelihood may work. For instance for OLS let's say you have test.data = time.vec^-alpha + error then you could take logs at both sides and go for log(test.data) = -alpha * log(time.vec). In R you can do that with the lm function. lm(log(test.data)~-1+log(time.vec))